# I've buit an example grid, and now looking to import API data in react-virtualized

Tags: react-virtualized

So I've built the example grid from react-virtualized, and now looking to grab data from an API and have a grid rendered.

What's the preferred method for grabbing API data in react? Axios? Fetch?

Answer (score 0):

The most stable and that requires the least boilerplate code is Axios. 
Take a look on this nice article.

https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/fetch-vs-axios-js-for-making-http-requests-2b261cdd3af5

I hope it helps you :)

Comment: I would suggest you Pure Axios  :) 
As their team, always maintain their repos regularly.

They are very responsive !

Comment: thanks Edivan! I went with react-axios solely because it's going to help me get used to seeing React-style code. I've asked another question I think you may be interested in looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663944/trying-to-combine-an-api-request-with-a-grid-rendering